# Probability with conditional and partial solution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

My Question reads:

Three cards were drawn from a deck.

a) If the first card a hearts, what is the probability that all three cards are hearts?

b) If at least one of the cards was a hearts, what is the probability that all three cards are hearts?

This is the solution that I have thought of so far for a and want to see how this helps me for b.

**Solution**

a) I know this is a conditional so I let H=the first card chosen is a heart, F=all three cards are hearts and then found P(F|H)=P(F $\cap$H)/ P(H).

I found P(H) to be 13/52 because there are 13 cards of hearts. 
The I found P(F $\cap$H) to be $\binom{13}3$/ $\binom{52}3$ and finally I said P(F|H)=22/425. However I think I may have calculated P (F$\cap$H) wrong as I might be missing a $\binom{4}1$ for picking the suit.

Is my solution correct or does it need to be modified to help me with part b?

Would part b best be solved by considering the compliment?

Comment: Looks fine to me ... I don't see why you are worrying about "picking the suit".

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Okay thank you, I was just taking into consideration picking the suit of hearts first.

Comment: @AntoineMathys Right, because this is saying picking a hearts first and all three hearts which is the same as saying picking all three hearts.

Answer (score 0):

> > a) If the first card was of hearts, what is the probability that all three cards are hearts?
>
> a) I know this is a conditional so I let H=the first card chosen is a heart, F=all three cards are hearts and then found $P(F\mid H)=P(F\cap H)/ P(H)$.
>
> I found $P(H)$ to be $13/52$ because there are 13 cards of hearts. The I found $P(F \cap H)$ to be $\binom {13}3/\binom{52}{3}$ and finally I said $P(F\mid H)=22/425$. However I think I may have calculated $P (F\cap H)$ wrong as I might be missing a $\binom 4 1$ for picking the suit.

No, you were correct.   The $\binom{13}{3}/\binom{52}{3}$ measures the probability for selecting 3 from 13 heart card when selecting 3 from 52 cards.   *That is okay.*   There's no need to count selections of suit because (1) in the numerator you are selecting all hearts, and (2) in the denominator you aren't selecting from any particular suit.

To confirm your result, notice that the probability for selecting three hearts given that the first card is a heart is equal to: the probability for selecting $2$ from $12$ hearts when selecting an additional $2$ cards from the $51$ cards that are not the first card(a heart).$$\binom{12}2/\binom{51}{2} = 22/425$$

> > b) If at least one of the cards was of hearts, what is the probability that all three cards are hearts?

Well, you know that there are $\binom {13}3$ ways to select $3$ from $13$ hearts, and likewise $\binom{52-13}{3}$ ways to select $3$ from $39$ non-hearts (thus selecting zero hearts).   If we let $X$ be the count of hearts, that's $\mathsf P(X=3)=\binom{13}3/\binom {52}3$ and $\mathsf P(X=0)=\binom{39}3/\binom{52}3$.    Use this to find $\mathsf P(X=3\mid X\neq 0)$, which is the conditional probability you seek.

> Use Bayes' Rule and the Law of Complementary Probabilities.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying, so I should consider removing those cases where there are no hearts since we want at least 1. I am just not seeing how to apply Bayes in this situation. Also, I am not too familiar with your notation towards the end as I have not learned this. Is this just counting how many hearts there are?

Comment: Oh wait, we can use Bayes because in a we found P( F|H) and in P we are doing P (H|F) right?

Comment: @Sam $X=3$ is just notation for "three hearts (among the three cards drawn)"; call it the event $T$ if you prefer.  Likewise $X=0$ is the event for "zero hearts", call it $N$, and "at least one heart" is $X\neq 0$, or $X\geq 1$ or $N^\complement$ (the complement of $N$).  Then you are seeking $\mathsf P(X=3\mid X\neq 0)~=~\mathsf P(T\mid N^\complement)$ .

Comment: Then we can use the answer for a because this is the case of one heart chosen at least and apply Bayes' formula?

Comment: No, you cannot use the answer for (a), because "at least one heart" means that it could be the first, second, or third heart, but these events are not disjoint (there are common outcomes among them).

Comment: Oh okay I see I think I was not reading the problem correctly. Then I apply Bayes' to the P(T|N$^c$). But I use complementary to find P( N$^c$)